# cannot resolve a specific bundle from a manifest file

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I downloaded a plugin for java bytecode metamodelling for eclipse.
I got problems running the application.
I have to import the Plugin as projects into eclipse and opening a new eclipse by running the plugin.
I get an error in the Manifest file as you can see in the screenshot.
The other bundles can be imported correctly, I just don't know why "org.objectweb.asm.util" can't be imported.

Screenshot of the Manifest file:
[image: Screenshot of the Manifest file]

Answer (score 0):

You can't use `*` in a Bundle id in the `Require-Bundle` entries in the MANIFEST.MF. The entries are the ids of plugins, you must add a seperate item to the list for each plugin you require. The ids are **not** package names.

Comment: I removed "*" but i still get the same error. the bundle cannot be solved.
I Hope you have some other solution.

Comment: Well you probably have the plugin id wrong, but since you haven't told us anything about what these plugins are we can't help with the ids. Note that this is **not** a list of package names, only the plugin ids should be included in this list.

Comment: If you switch to the *Dependencies* tab and in *Required Plug-ins* click *Add...*, the *Plug-in Selection* dialog will show all available plug-ins. The target platform of these plug-in can be edited in *Window > Preferences: Plug-in Development > Target Platform*.